# $rootScope not defined in a factory / service

Tags: angularjs

I have a code like this:

```
    angular.module('app')
    .factory('ME', function($http, $location, $rootScope){

       return {
        search: function(search_data, success, $rootScope) {
           $rootScope.errors = "lalala";
        }
       }
    });
```

And when I am calling a function search() and when I debug, I get an error saying that `$rootScope` is undefined. How do I make a use of `$rootScope` in a factory?

Comment: well, I have found an answer to my own question :/ Just to delete `$rootScope` from `search` function, that is what was clearing the results.

Comment: Scopes are passed to controllers, not factories.

Comment: @DavinTryon You are correct in your statement, but $rootScope is a service in this instance.

Comment: @DavinTryon are you saying that a good "angular way" is not to pass the scopes to the factories, instead to use factories with it's own variables to return the values to controllers and then use scope variables with factory variables?  (If I explained that well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question lies within my first comment on the question. In order to clear this message you **would need to delete** a `$rootScope` from a `search` function arguments. - `function(search_data, success, $rootScope)`. **That is what is clearing the results.**

But I wanted to post something more, and that is a comment that this approach should be modified and probably not to use the root scope in the first place. In this case it probably should, as we are setting an error message, but if it would be any other values then you should get rid of the `$rootScope` and add local variables, that can be later returned from a function method. Like this:

```
 angular.module('app')
    .factory('ME', function($http, $location, $rootScope){

       var result;

       return {
        search: function(search_data, success) {
           result = "lalala";
        },
        update: function(){
           result = "tralala";
        },

        message: function(){return result;} 
       }
    });
```

I am adding this as a further explanation, as in general I was hoping to get the better understanding when and how to use `rootScopes`